# ¿Como pasar este codigo PDO a mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

me gustaría pasar este codigo a mysqli, no entiendo mucho lo que quiere decir despues de la consulta sql:

```
function registeractive(){
// conexion de base de datos
$conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
$SQL = 'SELECT register FROM config WHERE idconfig = 1';
$sentence = $conexion -> prepare($SQL);
$sentence -> execute();
$resultados = $sentence -> fetchAll();
if (empty($resultados)){
  # code...
}else{
 foreach ($resultados as $key){
    $activo = $key['register'];
  }
}
return $activo;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Por que quisieras pasar el código que no sabes como funciona a usar otra librería que evidentemente tampoco conoces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes el mismo código pero utilizando MySQLi.

```
<?php
function registeractive() {
    $conn = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'base');
    $stmt = 'SELECT register FROM config WHERE idconfig = 1';
    $sentence = $conn->prepare($stmt);
    $sentence->execute();
    $result = $sentence->fetchAll();
    if (empty($result)) {
        # code...
    } else {
        foreach ($resultados as $key) {
            return $key['register'];
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres conocer más sobre MySQLi, te invito a leer la [documentación disponible en la página de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.php).